# Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract AstToken {
uint256 public totalSupply;

mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

function AstToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public{
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
}
```

}

I think everything is fine but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit later, I found a fix on the internet. If there is someone here trying to find solution here is what you should do:

So I used :

```
function AstToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public{
balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
totalSupply = _initialSupply;}
```

But insted you should use:

```
    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) public{
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
}
```

Comment: can you tell why i am getting this error for below code?
```// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Token{
    string public name="dank token";
    string public symbol="DAPP";
    uint256 public decimals=18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;


    constructor() public{
        totalSupply=1000000*(10**decimals);
    }
}

```